# No matter if I change my variable to str or int, terminal will give me a syntax error

Tags: python, string, integer

I am having a little bit of confusion regarding to a response I keep getting in the terminal I run the code. I am a making a simple game with a simple input interface, and every turn for the player I would like to show how many tries they have used up for that level. Here is my whole code:

```
import random
import time

# I will fist make variables for the time breaks. S is for short, M is for medium and L is for long

S = 0.2
M = 0.7
L = 1.1

class Level_1_activated():

    def get_name(self):

        # This function simply asks the name of the player

        name = input("Before we start, what is your name? ")

        time.sleep(S)
        print("You said your name was: " + name)

    def try_again(self):

        # This asks the player if they want to try again, and shows the progress of the level
        
        answer = (input("Do you want to try again? "))
        time.sleep(M)

        if answer == "yes":
            print("Alright!, well I am going to guess that you want to play again")
            time.sleep(M)
            return True

        else:
            print("Thank you for playing the game, I hope you have better luck next time")
            # This is the return statement that stops the while loop 
            return False


    def find_rand_num(self, random):

        # This is the core of the level, where the player just chooses numbers between 1 and 10
        time.sleep(S)   

        print("The computer is choosing a random number between 1 and 10... beep beep boop")
        time.sleep(L)

        # The list of numbers for the level that the player is on at the moment
        num_list = [1,10]
        number = random.choice(num_list)

        ques = (input("guess your number, since this is the first level you need to choose a number between 1 and 10  "))
        print(ques)

        if ques == str(number):
            time.sleep(S)
            print("Congratulations! You got the number correct!")
            time.sleep(L)
            
            print("Good job! You will be progressing to the 2nd level now!")
            time.sleep(L*2)

            # Yet another return statement for the while loop
            return "Found"
            
        elif input != number:

            time.sleep(M)
            print("Oops, you got the number wrong")


def run_game():
    tries = 1
    while tries < 6:

        if tries < 2:
            Level_1_activated().get_name()
            print("You have used up " + tries + " of your tries already")
        
        res = Level_1_activated().find_rand_num(random)
        if res == "Found":
            break

        checker = Level_1_activated().try_again()
        if checker is False:
            break
        
        tries += 1
        print("Remember you have used up " + tries + " of your tries")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_game()
```

I will narrow down the code to where I think it is a little bit more relevant:

```
    tries = 1
    while tries < 6:

    if tries < 2:
        Level_1_activated().get_name()
        print("You have used up " + tries + " of your tries already")
    
    res = Level_1_activated().find_rand_num(random)
    if res == "Found":
        break

    checker = Level_1_activated().try_again()
    if checker is False:
        break
    
    tries += 1
    print("Remember you have used up " + tries + " of your tries")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_game()
```

I am getting an error in this line:

```
    print("Remember you have used up " + tries + " of your tries")
```

It is saying: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str. I have tried to change

```
tries
```

to:

```
str(tries) or even int(tries)
```

I am not sure on how to solve this. Thank you for your time, and I hope you have an answer that would solve my error.

Comment: If all of those things guys mentioned doesn't work maybe you didn't saved the file before running it? It happens sometimes I guess. Because formating or converting integer to str works fine.

Comment: I did unfortunately save so that

Comment: is not the problem

Comment: Did you changed everywhere in your printing the **tries** variable?

Comment: right before the print statement I add 1 to the variable tries

Comment: You have another one print with this variable at the start of the loop.And is this the whole code?

Comment: That is the whole code yes, let me put the print statement in the beginning of the run_game loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine for me when I use str(tries) in the print line.

```
tries=10
print("Remember you have used up " + str(tries) + " of your tries")
```

**Output**

```
Remember you have used up 10 of your tries
```

Can you please check the code once again, I think it should work fine.

Comment: still getting the same

Comment: Can you copy my code in a separate file (just the 2 lines) and try to run it? and see if it works

Comment: yes it worked. I don't know why it does not work on my lvl1 file though

Comment: After you modify the code to str(tries) what error do you get?

Comment: I just solved it. I put the print statement at the beginning of the loop and I did it through the idle not vscode, and it worked! Thank you for helping! have an upvote

Comment: Most Welcome!! Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Remember you have used up {} of your tries".format(tries))
print("Remember you have used up {t} of your tries".format(t=tries))
```

You need to format the string, passing the value to a placeholder.

Comment: I am still getting the same thing which is kind of wierd